# How to convert long data to wide in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Similar question:

- [Long/wide data to wide/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534500/long-wide-data-to-wide-long)

(I got duplicate index error when using the method given in that link)

## MWE

```
df_long = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
          'variable': ['height', 'height', 'width', 'width'],
          'value': [10, 20, 1, 2]})
print(df_long)
  name variable  value
0    A   height     10
1    B   height     20
2    A    width      1
3    B    width      2



============================

Requires answer

  name  height  width
0    A      10      1
1    B      20      2
```

## My attempt

```py
(df_long.set_index(['name'])
        .stack()
        .unstack(0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Comment: use `pivot_table`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_long.pivot_table("value",["name"], "variable")

variable  height  width
name                   
A             10      1
B             20      2
```

Comment: add .reset_index() if you want a reduced index.